# to pass RAII structure as 2D-array into a function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

There is a function, accepting 2D-array:

```
void foo ( double ** p ) 
{ /*writing some data into p*/ }
```

I wouldn't like to pass raw 2D array into this function because i don't want to manage memory calling `new` and `delete`. Also i wouldn't like to change function signature to `void foo ( std::vector< std::vector<double> >& )`. And i can't make `foo` as a template function (in my project it's a COM-interface method).

I would like to pass some RAII object decoring it raw-one, like

```
void foo ( double * p ){}
std::vectore<double> v(10);
p( &v[0] );
```

Is there way to do this for 2D-arrays? I tried

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
foo( &v[0][0] )
```

and

```
std::vector< std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> > v;
```

but i get compile errors `error C2664 - cannot convert parameter`.

Also, can one be sure that raw address arithmetics inside the function works ok in this case?

No C++11, the sizes of 2D-array are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to change:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
foo( &v[0][0] )
```

to

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
std::vector<int*> v_ptr;
for (...) {
    v_ptr[i] = &v[i][0];
}
foo( &v_ptr[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, at least my compilator processes it with no errors! I'd like to know, can one be sure about using address arithmetics inside ``foo``?

Comment: @fogbit Yes, this should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Although Andreas already gave an answer to your question that solves your particular problem, I would like to point out, that although that works, it is probably not what you want to do.

As you are using C++ (and not an easier to use language), I am assuming that you care about performance. In that case your approach is in all likelihood wrong from the beginning, as `double**` represents an array of arrays (or rather *can represent*) and not a 2D array. Why is this bad? Because, just as with the `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` example, multiple allocations are required, and the resulting memory is non-contiguous (which is bad for the cache) unlike a `double array[N][M]`.

For 2D arrays you should in fact use 1D arrays with index calculation, which is far more cache-friendly. This of course does not allow `[x][y]`-style indexing (instead you have to use `[x+N*y]` or `[y+M*x]`, depending on your choice of "Fortran order" or "C order"), but avoids cache issues and only requires a single allocation (and a simple `double*`pointer).

If you are iterating all elements of the array as in

```
for(unsigned x = 0; x < N; ++x) for(unsigned y = 0; y < M; ++y)
{
    unsigned idx = y + M * x;
    p[idx] = bar(x, y); // equivalent to p[x][y] = bar(x,y) in the array-of-arrays case
}
```

You can even avoid the multiplications as this is basically just a 1D iteration with additional generation of 2D indices

```
for(unsigned x = 0, idx = 0; x < N; ++x) for(unsigned y = 0; y < M; ++y, ++idx)
{
    p[idx] = bar(x, y);
}
```